# Can't get Properties to ListView from each item in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps

I want to test ListView in xaml so i decide to create a little quiz( Easy maths questions with 3 answers to choose). So i create a model of question, viewmodel of question( with all properties from my model question), and finally a ViewModelClass where i have observableCollection of viewmodel questions.
When I bind my ListView ItemSource property with my ObservableCollection the only thing i get from each item is Method ToString(). I have no idea how to fix that. 
Here is my code:

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=viewModel}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" >
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">
                <Run Text="Question "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding QuestionNumber}"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="How much is:  "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding First}"/>
                <Run Text=" * "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Second}"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <!-- Here should be three answers to choose -->
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

My ViewModel Question(each item in ObservableColletion which i call Questions):

```
    class QuestionViewModel
{
    Question myQuestion;
    int questionNumber;

    public QuestionViewModel(Question question,int number)
    {
        myQuestion=question;
        questionNumber = number;
    }

    public int First
    {
        get
        {
            return myQuestion.first;
        }
    }

    public int Second
    {
        get
        {
            return myQuestion.second;
        }
    }

    public int QuestionNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return questionNumber;
        }
    }

    public int FirstAnswer
    {
        get
        {
            return myQuestion.answers[0];
        }
    }

    public int SecondAnswer
    {
        get
        {
            return myQuestion.answers[1];
        }
    }

    public int ThirdAnswer
    {
        get
        {
            return myQuestion.answers[2];
        }
    }

}
```

And ViewModelClass:

```
    class QuestionsViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<QuestionViewModel> Questions{get;private set;}

    public QuestionsViewModel()
    {
        Questions = new ObservableCollection<QuestionViewModel>();
        GenerateQuestion(10,10);
    }

    private void GenerateQuestion(int howmuch,int range)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < howmuch; i++)
            Questions.Add(new QuestionViewModel(new Question(range),i+1));
    }

}
```

Comment: http://www.codecisions.com/custom-ivalueconverter-for-binding-a-wpf-textbox-to-an-integer/

Comment: Yes i know i need to convert int to string but i don't see any properties from my list.

Comment: could you spend some time to edit your post, format the code block to make it more readable?

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` does not know how to render each `QuestionViewModel` in a `ListViewItem`. This is where a `DataTemplate` comes into play.

You forget to define a `DataTemplate` for each `ListViewItem`. Try this

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock... //your text blocks
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```